# Test whenever a value x is greater by exactly 1 compared to a value y modulo 3

Tags: php, modulo, modular-arithmetic

How do I check that x is 1 greater (ahead) of y in a modulo sense (mod 3)?

This is when x = 0 and y = 2, when x = 1, y = 0 and when x = 2, y = 1.

I tried testing like this:

```
php -a
php > $x = 0;
php > $y = 2;
php > echo ($x - $y) % 3;
-2
php > $x = 1;
php > $y = 0;
php > echo ($x - $y) % 3;
1
php > $x = 2;
php > $y = 1;
php > echo ($x - $y) % 3;
1
```

It is not working for the case where x = 0 and y = 2.  How can I calculate this so that $x is 'ahead' of $y by 1 in a modulo sense?

Comment: (($x - $y) % 3  == 1)

Comment: What **exactly** do you mean by "greater of y in a modulo sense"? Please share details of the expected output of your algorithm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will first explain my understanding of your following sentence:

> How do I check that x is 1 greater (ahead) of y in a modulo sense (mod 3)?

Following the examples provided, I assume you mean that, if 1 is added to $y, and we take the mod 3 of $y, we would get the mod 3 of $x.

With that in mind, we could write the following code, witch would return true if $x is "ahead" of $y by 1. (I hope you can abstract that example to whatever situation you are facing):

```
function check($x, $y, $mod) {
   return $x % $mod == ($y + 1) % $mod;
}
//$x = 0 and $y = 2
echo check(0,2,3); //returns true

//$x = 1 and $y = 0
echo check(1,0,3); //returns true

//$x = 2 and $y = 1
echo check(2,1,3); //returns true

//$x = 0 and $y = 1
echo check(0,1,3); //returns false because $x is 2 "ahead" of $y
```

If you want a more generalized version of the function, with an arbitrary difference, you can use this (it should work with positive and negative differences):

```
function check($x, $y, $mod, $diff) {
   return $x % $mod == ($y + $diff) % $mod;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Why is it that you used 0 for `x` and 2 for `y`? (Sorry, but I'm not much of an algebraist.)

Although your situations are pretty much clarified, it doesn't make sense (at least for me) that `x` would be 1 bit ahead of `y` when it is clearly `0 < 2`.

As we know, the statement `(0 - 2) % 3` would be `-2` because the *mod* is 3, and `0 - 2` is -2, so the result is -2.

Mathematics can have some illogical sense (in my opinion) sometimes, so its worth noting that 0 isn't ahead of 2 (in the sense of programming variables) at all.

And to actually answer your question on calculation, you could have `x = 0` and `y = -1` as your variables instead, as per se the logic of your statement, then just increment by 1 for both variables, and the result is still the same.

---

**Proof:**

```php
<?php
    $x = 0
    $y = -1
    echo ($x - $y) % 3 // outputs 1
    echo (++$x - ++$y) % 3 // still outputs 1
    echo (++$x - ++$y) % 3 // also outputs 1
    echo (++$x - ++$y) % 3 // yep, still the same
    echo (++$x - ++$y) % 3 // alright, you get the deal
?>
```